# Digital Magnitude Comparator: LSb first or MSb first

Tags: digital-logic, digital-comparator

Most of the comparator designs/algorithms are based on MSb first approach (i.e, starting the comparison from MSb of the two numbers), which seems to be effective approach intuitively.
I was just curious to know, where might we find LSb based comparison to be more suited as compared to a MSb first.

Comment: Is it Bytes or bits?

Comment: least and most significant bits

Answer (score 2):

There is a [sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Least_significant_digit_radix_sorts) which sorts from the least significant *digit*, where the size of the *digit* can be chosen arbitrarily, and is sometimes set to a single bit. This is the only place I can think of off the top of my head where you would wish to compare the least significant bit first, though I'm sure there are other places.

EDIT: Forgot to put the link in there!

Answer (score 1):

If you compare from MSB first, you will generally get your answer faster. Decimal 20 is obviously bigger than 15, just from a comparison of the MSD. If you start from LSD, then you have to compare the whole word.

Whether that's an advantage or not depends on the rest of the system. If it's clocked, then you will have to guarantee that the worst case comparison can be done within your system clock, which renders any average speed-up irrelevant.

If the criterion is power dissipation, and you can actually stop the comparison circuit once it has reached a conclusion, for instance if it's a serial word comparator that runs one bit at a time, it will use less power on average. You may have to be doing a lot of comparisons to see any significant power reduction, but if you're aiming for mW, every little may help.

Comment: This answers the opposite of the original question.

Comment: You're right, it does. I think that means 'never' then!

Comment: ... unless there's some quirk of the system it is being added to, like data is already being shifted around LSB first, and keeping the order will be more economical.

Comment: I saw one of the websites that one such application can be in DSP where we might require speed of comparison operation to be below a certain limit. Although it seems a bit absurd to me(with limited knowledge of DSP), may be someone with a bit more background can elaborate on this